# Why am I getting this syntax error in micropython?

Tags: python, pi-pico, micropython

I am testing the raspberry pi pico, and am getting a strange syntax error. I have no idea why.

```
from time import sleep
led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
wait = 0.1
while True
    for x in range(9)
        wait += 0.1
        led.toggle()
        sleep(wait*1000)
    for x in range(9)
        wait -= 0.1
        led.toggle()
        sleep(wait*1000)
```

I am runninig this on the pico, but I just get

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried debugging but everything seems to be right.

Comment: Are you using a pico-w? Change 25 to “LED”

Comment: `Edit your question` and tell us the debugging you have done.  There is no point in us making suggestions you have tried.

Comment: Generally, your question is lucking research effort and any sort of effort fixing the issue.  Next time try to address a problem yourself before posting it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting syntax errors, because you made syntax mistakes in your Python code. Control-flow statements in python opening an indented block are followed by colon (:). So syntactically  correct code would look like:

```
from time import sleep
led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
wait = 0.1
while True:
    for x in range(9):
        wait += 0.1
        led.toggle()
        sleep(wait*1000)
    for x in range(9):
        wait -= 0.1
        led.toggle()
        sleep(wait*1000)
```